# hi, im new to python and i was wondering how would i go about adding values to lists based from the index of another list

Tags: python-3.1

> > > new_list =[0,0,0,0]
> > >
> > > for x_list in random_list: # list of list
> > >
> > > for x in x_list:
> > >
> > > if x == "I" or "i":
> > >
> > > list_index = x_list.index(x)
> > >
> > > new_list[list_index] += 1

Lets say the random_list was [['x','x','I','I'],['x','x','I','x']]

it should output [0,0,2,1], but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the built-in `enumerate`, which allows you to iterate over the objects and indices at the same time. your inner loop could then be

```
for list_index, x in enumerate(x_list):
    if x == "I" or "i":
        new_list[list_index] += 1
```

and it should do what you want

*PS*

One more gotcha: `if x == "I" or "i":` should actually be `if x == "I" or x == "i":`